# filefield serializer is not parsing the file object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model in my application:

```
class GRNRFIDSerials(models.Model):

    grn = models.ForeignKey(Grn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='grnrfid/', null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to upload the file in the ORM like the following:

```
class GRNRFIDSerialsUploadAPIView(CreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = GrnRFIDSerialsSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        owner = request.user.pk
        print("reached")
        d = request.data.copy()
        d['owner'] = owner
        print("d", d)
        serializer = GrnRFIDSerialsSerializer(data=d)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

where `d` is :

```
d <QueryDict: {'no_of_fileA_files': ['1'], 'grn': ['479'], 'viewType': ['Pool Operator'], 'companyId': ['52'], 
'document': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: EPC (4).xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spr
    eadsheetml.sheet)>], 'owner': [27]}>
```

This runs without an error but n the database entry filefield is shown as blank. How do I upload the file object?

Comment: The two are practically the same thing under the hood.

Comment: Please add how you defined the serializer and how you wrote the create API in frontend.

Comment: @Metalgear is right, we need to see your serializer. `d` does not contain any key named `file`, but your model expects one to be present. So at some point your serializer has to manipulate the incoming data before passing it to `GRNRFIDSerials.objects.create()`.

Comment: there is must problem in your serializer. any thing other than serializer is right in your code.

Comment: By the way, @RahulSharma, you should ask a new question instead of completely editing an old question to a new one.